# Return the position of an item in a table if it's in it. [Py 3.4]

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
cmds = ['time']

while True:
    inp = input('::> ')
    sinp = inp.split()
    if str(sinp[0]) in cmds:
        print('mkay.')
```

Would I be able to get the position of the item in the table, if the name and input match? Thanks!

UPDATE: Here's my updated code:

```
cmds = ['k', '1']

while True:
inp = input('>>> ')
sinp = inp.split()
try:
    if str(sinp[0]) in cmds:
        cmds.index(sinp)
        print(sinp)
except ValueError:
    print('Unknown Command')
```

It's returning me 'Unknown Command' whenever I type in k or 'k'. Same goes for 1, however '1' works. What's the reason for this?

Oh god. Sorry to trouble you guys, I did just sinp instead of sinp[0] for .index. ouch.

UPDATE: it's not accepting '1' or 1. even though it's in the cmds table.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong about not needing `str()` casting.  Wrap input as `str(input('>>> '))`.  You can then remove it from `str(sinp[0])`.

Comment: @Mark Perryman  - Won't that require the user to surround their input with quotation marks?

Comment: Update: still works exactly like it used to. I removed the str() casting from the if statement earlier too. As I said, it works exactly the same when I put it round input(). It won't accept numbers, that's why I'm using raw input.

Comment: Please add the updated, updated code.

Comment: It's there, just move the str() from the if statement to the input. It's the last formatted code box in the main question. Right after the 1st 'UPDATE:'.

Comment: The code in the question still has `sinp` where it should be `sinp[0]`.  It would be helpful to see the actual code, as I suspect there is a typo somewhere.

Comment: github.com/iPhynx/simplOS/ - I changed it up a bit instead of overcomplicating it. However I added a dictionary earlier too for commands. Didn't work, shame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `you_list.index(the_item)`

```
cmds = ['time', 'yep']

while True:
    inp = input('::> ')
    sinp = inp.split()
    if str(sinp[0]) in cmds:
        print('mkay.')
        print cmds.index(inp)
```

Output:

```
::> time
mkay.
0
::> yep
mkay.
1
::>
```

Comment: The str() gives an error message that the input must not be raw but in string form. So I ditched that. The code you gave me works great and I added in 'else: print('Unknown Command'). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If **cmds** is the "table", then `cmds.index` gives you the position in which the matching string is.

Answer (score 1):

The `index()` method of the list is what you need.

```
>>> cmds = ['e', 'r', 't']
>>> cmds.index('e')
0
>>> cmds.index('t')
2
>>> cmds.index('y')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'y' is not in list
```

Make sure you put it in a `try`, `except` block in case the command is not found.

For example,

```
inp = str(input('::> '))
sinp = inp.split()
print("You are trying to run command:", sinp[0])
try:
    print(cmds.index(sinp[0]))
except ValueError:
    print("Command not recognised")
```

Comment: What's the code I need to display an error message and keep going? Isn't something along the lines of 'exception'? Thanks so much.

Comment: Added notes about exception handling.  It is worth reading up on exceptions as they are a better way to handle errors than lots of `if` statements.

Comment: I just edited in an updated version of my code with the exception for ValueError.